# Why does my USB modem produce multiple /dev/ttyUSB* files? In that, which one I have to select for AT commands?

Tags: usb

[image]Why does my USB modem produce multiple /dev/ttyUSB* files?
In that, which one I have to select for AT commands?

I'm using SIM7600 module in Linux system.
This is my lsusb output.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search enginre results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting. Also, please edit your post to include the output of `lsusb`.

Answer (score 0):

USB devices can provide multiple USB interfaces, e.g. USB 3G/4G modems can emulate both a USB Ethernet adapter and a CD-ROM device containing drivers for the host OS. That's what you're looking at.

Like AdminBee said, you can use the `lsusb` output to check what you're actually dealing with.

You can also use this Debian wiki article to learn how to identify USB ports:

https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB

Lastly make sure you have the newest version of http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids installed.

Comment: In which one I have to test the AT commands?

Comment: You can try all of them one by one and see which works.

Comment: How to test AT commands, because I seen many posts related to this. I'm not sure which one method will work.

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/modem-hayes.html
http://ps-2.kev009.com/pcpartnerinfo/ctstips/ea5e.htm

Comment: Is any other method available other than minicom? minicom is like a puTTY software only right. I have gone through the `screen` command but it's not working.

Comment: Why can't you use `minicom`? screen is a terminal application, it's not meant for a serial console.

Comment: `minicom` also a terminal emulator only. So, I'm trying to do by serial port programming.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script to get the particular address of an AT modem.
I'm connecting to all of the possible ttyUSBx ports and trying to send an AT command.
Script needs picocom >= v3.0

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for tty in $(ls /dev/ttyUSB*); do
    echo "Checking $tty"
    picocom -qrX -b 9600 $tty
    sleep 1
    result=$(echo "AT&F" | picocom -qrix 1000 $tty)
    if [ "$result" = "AT&F" ]; then
        echo "Found AT compatible modem at $tty"
    else
        echo "No AT compatible modem at $tty"
    fi
done
```